# The difference between "if" and "even if"

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, conditionals

I've tried to figure out the difference between "if" and "even if".
My reasoning is as follows. Do I correctly understand?

> 1. Even if your partner were a saint, he would not accept your
>    proposal.
>
> =Even your partner is a saint. Regardless of it, he doesn’t accept your proposal.

or

> =Even your partner will be a saint. Regardless of it, he will not accept your proposal.

.

> 2. Even if you had not seen the message, you could have imagined what
>    it meant.
>
> =Even you didn't see the message. In spite of it, you imagined what it meant.

.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.

The reason why I thought as above is because of the following.

When "If" is used in second type conditional, If clause has an unreal or hypothetical condition/situation, and a main clause is a possible result from if clause.
It is kind of < cause-and-effect relationship >.

No condition in If clause take places and then no result in the main clause follows.

e.g.)

> If I had a partner, I would go to a dancing party.
>
> =I don't/will not have any partner, and I cannot go to a dancing party.

However, “even if” is a condition but is not one relevant to a main clause. They are NOT < cause-and-effect relationship.>.

Even if clause doesn't impact on a content of a main clause.
The under-written "even if clause + main cause" can be paraphrased like these with indicative moods.

> 1. Even if your partner were a saint, he would not accept your
>    proposal.
>
> =Even you are partner are a saint. Regardless of it, he doesn't accept your proposal.

.

> 2. Even if you had not seen the message, you could have imagined what
>    it meant.
>
> =Even you didn't see the message. In spite of it, you imagined what it meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an idea of the difference here, but it is hard to tell with some of the grammatical errors.

"Even if [condition], [clause]" means that--regardless of whether or not the condition is true--the clause will still be true/happen. It is often used with hypothetical conditions. "Even if" implies that the condition is not true.

E.G.
"Even if your partner were a saint, he would not accept your proposal."

Can be paraphrased as "If your partner was magically turned into a saint, he would still refuse your proposal".

In this case, "your partner" is not a saint, and "even if" can be used because no matter the condition of sainthood, "your partner" will not accept the proposal.

"If [condition], [clause]" means that the clause will be true/happen if the condition is true. It does not imply that the condition is false or hypothetical.

E.G. "If I had a partner, I would go to a dancing party."
Can be roughly paraphrased as "If I get a partner, I will go to the dancing party."

In this case, the speaker may find a partner and the clause may become true (i.e. he will go to the party), whereas "Even if I had a partner, I wouldn't go to the dancing party" would mean that the speaker will never go to the dancing partner, regardless of whether or not he gets a partner.

Comment: Hi, 『Even if clause』 still has a hypothetical condition/situation. So I am sorry to tell you I don't think it is not true. Instead, the condition might be true or not, but in spite of it, a speaker still do something that he or she wants/thinks to do.

Comment: Yeap, before expressing my opinion to you I don't want to get you mad. /// Anyway, when the past tense is used in "Even if" as you said, "Even if" clause implies the condition is hypothetical but unreal and improbable. However, I mean, when the present tense is used in "Even if" clause In that case, I cannot say this "Even if" clause implies the condition is unreal. Thus, I say generally, "Even if" clause let me consider check the context and the form of main clause following it.

Comment: For example) 【Even if Mr. Tae is a good teacher, I will not take his class】: This "Even if" clause means that Mr. Tae is a really good teacher, Nevertheless in spite of this fact, I will not take his class. So the "Even if" clause can be understood under the indicative mood with present tense.

Comment: On the other hand, For example) 【Even if Mr. Tae was a good teacher, I will not take his class】: This "Even if" clause means that Mr. Tae was a really good teacher. Nevertheless despite this fact, I will not take his class.. So the "Even if" clause can be understood under the indicative mood with past tense.

Comment: One more, For example) 【Even if Mr. Tae was a good teacher, I would not take his class】: This "Even if" clause means that Mr. Tae is not a really good teacher but I am going to hypothetically think I imagine he was really good teacher. However regardless of it, I don't take his class or I will not take his class.

Comment: Ah~~~Ha... Okay. /// "Even if Mr. Tae was a good teacher, I will not take his class." (Not grammatically speaking, but it would not make sense and a native speaker would be very unlike to say such a thing). /// Maybe native American English speakers something was true in the past. And now they want to express something about the past true or fact. In that case you guys may use "Although" or "Though (as conjunction" or "Even though".

Comment: For example) 【Although or Though or Even though Mr. Tae was a good teacher, I will not take his class." - Maybe I think some context is needed, if this sentence can be possible. Perhaps, a speaker knows that Mr. Tae was a good teacher as  far as he remember. Now he has a chance to take Mr. Tae's class in school. But he doesn't want to take his class due to some other reasons such as scheduling conflict or something.

Comment: "Although or Though or Even though Mr. Tae was a good teacher, I will not take his class." This makes perfect sense, but "Even if" would not work here.

Comment: Wow~ :) ~~!! Thank you so much, maxbear123~! /// Okay, come to think of the following agian. 【Even if Mr. Tae is a good teacher, I will not take his class】: This "Even if" clause means that Mr. Tae WILL BE a really good teacher, → This one is more proper, I guess. Because using "Even If" means that a speaker don't tell 100% true fact, when I remind myself of a first conditional "If clause".

Comment: When I really say the fact that Mr. Tae is 100% a really good Teacher and it is true. Then I don't want to take his class. In that case, I have to say like this: 【Although or Though or Even though Mr. Tae is a good teacher(100% Ture), I will not take his class.

Comment: Anyway the reason why I previously composed the wrong sentence(but not grammatically) 【 Even if Mr. Tae was a good teacher, I will not take his class." 】 is that I have read the following paragraph from Practical English Usage. /// `However, students sometimes think that these are the only possibilities, and become confused when they meet sentences like 【 If she didn't phone this morning, then she's probably away. 】 (‘What’s this? A fourth conditional?’).`

Comment: `It is important to realise that if is not only used in special structures with will and would; it can also be used, like other conjunctions, in ordinary structures with normal verb forms. (A research study carried out in the 1990s found that less than 25% of if-conditional sentences follow the traditional ‘first’, 'second’ and ‘third’ patterns.) 
For example) 【If you didn't study physics at school, you won't understand this book.】. 【Because you didn't study physics at school, you won't understand this book.】`

Comment: Okay, I am going to post a new and further question. By the way your just mentioned sentence can be understood like this? : If you have questions about other phrases, and (If I were you) I would open a new questions???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118745/discussion-between-tae-bbong-e-and-maxbear123).

Answer (score 1):

"Even if" is a way to express a **definiteness of an outcome**. It is a way to say:

> "In the scenario in which these things happen, they will still have no impact on the outcome" .

"Even if" can be used to **refute** an argument.

> "If he were a saint, he would marry me!" - "No, he would not marry you, *even if* he were a saint"

"Even if" can be used to shift **responsibility**.

> "He was drunk, that is why he crashed the car" - "No, because the pedal was broken, He would have still crashed the car, even if he were not drunk"

"If" expresses a basic conditional relationship that can be used in a number of ways and modified in other ways, such as "Even if".