# Further questions: Even if with subjunctive mood or indicative mood

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, subjunctives

My main question is; Even if can be used with subjunctive mood or something like indicative mood.
Actually I do know Even if used with subjunctive mood. But my main point is latter one.

=======================================================.

Before asking all of you about it, First of all, I have learned something about "Even if".

[The difference between "if" and "even if"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272730/the-difference-between-if-and-even-if/272737?noredirect=1#comment508731_272737)

In the meantime, I double-checked again two meanings of "Even if" by dictionaries.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/even_1#even_idmg_2
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/even-if
https://www.englishgrammar.org/even-if-and-even-though/

Also I have got the following feedback

> You use "Even if [condition]" when--despite the condition being false, the clause afterwards will still
> hold true.

I think this feedback would be right. But I don't agree with mentioning "false". Rather it contains unreal or hypothetical condition.

.

According to dictionaries, there are two kinds of usage about 2 sorts of meanings from https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/even_1#even_idmg_2

**1. Despite the possibility that; no matter whether**

**2. Despite the fact that; even though**

However, regarding 2. usage I think indicative mood sometimes looks applied to 『Even if clause and main clause』.

For example from https://www.lexico.com/definition/even_if

> • ‘My mother always did her best for me, even if there wasn't always enough to go around.’
>
> • ‘It was a brilliant piece of reactive warfare, even if it was not wholly successful.’
>
> • ‘They never doubted his love, even if he could not put it into words the rest of us would understand.’

Do you think those 【even if ~ clauses】 mentions unreal or hypothetical condition?
I don't think so. They now conveys real facts. Furthermore, If subjunctive mood is applied to those sentences, maybe be-verbs in them have to be inflected to "were" regardless of persons. As well main clauses have to come with modal verbs such as would / could / might / should. But as you can the above, subjunctive mood is not applied.

When I compare 1 usage's example sentences in Lexico website, the subjunctive mood is obviously applied to even if clause.

For example,

> • ‘It does not matter, even if it were to be clearly established that it had gone astray in the post.’

Therefore, if my reasoning is correct, I can say the following sentence.

1. Context: Mr. TJ is a good teacher. Now I have a chance to take his class, but I will not take his class due to some reasons such as scheduling conflict or something.

> → Even if Mr. TJ is a good teacher, I will not take his class.
>
> = Mr TJ is a good teacher. In spite of it, I will not take this class.
> .

2. Context: Mr. TJ was a good teacher, I will not take this class.

> → Even if Mr. TJ was a good teacher, I will not take his class.
>
> = Mr. TJ was a good teacher. Despite the fact, I will not take his class.
>
> (Maybe no native speakers say 2.-sentence. It is grammatical, though.)
> .

For your reference, the reason why the sentence from 2. context could be possible is that I have read some paragraph from Practical English Usage.
[image]

Comment: I think you're hopelessly overthinking this. ***Even if*** is just a more explicitly emphatic way of saying ***if***. The precise *implications* of that additional emphasis will vary according to context (sometimes *even if X* will imply *X is an extreme condition*, other times it implies *it's irrelevant whether X is true or not*, or perhaps something different again).

Comment: "  → Even if Mr. TJ is a good teacher, I will not take his class.

    = Mr TJ is a good teacher. In spite of it, I will not take this class. ." This is correct. This is not a hypothetical because you used "is". In the case of "Even if Mr. TJ was a good teacher, I would not take his class" it is a hypothetical, however, because you used "was".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica and maxbear123 / Okay, you mean regardless of what type of conditionals, I can make compose any sentences only if I can follow standard grammars and support those sentences with proper context. /// For example) When I am trying to say "possible condition" and "probable result" in that case, at least I have to say like this - 【 Even if Mr. TJ is a good teacher, I will not take his class 】. It is okay.

Comment: However if I want to say the above nuance, I cannot say like this 【 Even if Mr. TJ is a good teacher, I would not take his class. 】. according to one native speaker's feedback. https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/285524-If-she-lt-finishes-gt-early-she-lt-WOULD-gt-phone-me ☞ He says "Don't use would in the main clause of Type 1 conditionals. No, it doesn't make sense."

Comment: Non-native speakers place are too fond of the idea that there are a small number of ***completely distinct*** "conditionals" - and hence that identifying them ***by their assigned numbers*** is a useful part of learning how to reflect those conditions ***in words*** (grammatically). Native speakers can and do use all the highlighted alternatives in, say, *Even if Christmas Day 2025 **isn't / wasn't / were not** a Sunday, I **will / would** still go to church on that day.* And I doubt the speaker's choice would give you any idea ***whether the speaker knows*** what day it is / will be.